# Implementation of an MH Algorithm for Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, bayesian

I hope you are well and having a nice day. I am attempting to code an MH algorithm for a multiple linear regression model. I am following a tutorial online for simple linear regression using an MH algorithm and I plan on applying the principles myself to my multiple linear regression model, but I am running into a problem figuring our how to specify prior distributions for the parameters. Below, is the code.

```
trueA <- 5
trueB <- 0
trueSd <- 10
sampleSize <- 31
 
# create independent x-values 
x <- (-(sampleSize-1)/2):((sampleSize-1)/2)
# create dependent values according to ax + b + N(0,sd)
y <-  trueA * x + trueB + rnorm(n=sampleSize,mean=0,sd=trueSd)
 


 likelihood <- function(param){
    a = param[1]
    b = param[2]
    sd = param[3]
     
    pred = a*x + b
    singlelikelihoods = dnorm(y, mean = pred, sd = sd, log = T)
    sumll = sum(singlelikelihoods)
    return(sumll)   
}
```

This is the portion where I am running into problems. In the tutorial, the author now specifies that they  define prior distributions for the parameters. In this case, I would like to specify uninformative prior distributions for the slopes, coefficients, and standard deviation. The author says that they used uniform/normal distributions.

I found an example using Poisson regression, which looks like:

```
LogPriorFunction <- function(param){
        beta0 <- param[1] 
        beta1 <- param[2] 
        beta0prior <- dnorm(beta0, 0, sqrt(100), log=TRUE)
        beta1prior <- dnorm(beta1, 0, sqrt(100), log=TRUE)
        return(beta0prior + beta1prior) # Logarithm of prior distributions
}
```

But I am having trouble adapting it to the simple linear regression. Here is my attempt:

```
prior <- function(param){
        a = param[1]
        b = param[2]
        sd = param[3] 
        aprior = dnorm(a, 0, 1000, log=TRUE)
        bprior = dnorm(b, 0, 1000, log=TRUE)
        sdprior = 1/rgamma(sd, shape = .001, scale = .001)
        return(aprior + bprior + sdprior) # Logarithm of prior distributions
}
```

The rest of the code is:

```
posterior <- function(param){
   return (likelihood(param) + prior(param))

}
proposalfunction <- function(param){
    return(rnorm(3,mean = param, sd= c(0.1,0.5,0.3)))
}
 
run_metropolis_MCMC <- function(startvalue, iterations){
    chain = array(dim = c(iterations+1,3))
    chain[1,] = startvalue
    for (i in 1:iterations){
        proposal = proposalfunction(chain[i,])
         
        probab = exp(posterior(proposal) - posterior(chain[i,]))
        if (runif(1) < probab){
            chain[i+1,] = proposal
        }else{
            chain[i+1,] = chain[i,]
        }
    }
    return(chain)
}
 
startvalue = c(4,0,10)
chain = run_metropolis_MCMC(startvalue, 10000)
 
burnIn = 5000
acceptance = 1-mean(duplicated(chain[-(1:burnIn),]))
```

Finally, along with specifying the priors, I keep getting the warning message:

*Error in if (runif(1) < probab) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (runif(1) < probab) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*

I am not sure if this is related to my incorrectly specifying the prior distributions, as the author of the article gets similar results from the MH algorithm as running a simple linear regression model using the lm() function. Any help would with these issues would be greatly appreciated. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you.

As a reference, here is the link to the article:

https://khayatrayen.github.io/MCMC.html#defining_the_prior

Finally, here is a link to the article from where I tried to emulate the priors, but does Poisson regression and not linear regression:

https://rpubs.com/SaraGarcesCespedes/586440

Comment: Quick glance.. you add a normal proposal for the standard deviation. This can result in negative values , hence error in rgamma and so posterior.